# How can I drop a table in Bookshelf js?

Tags: express, mocha.js, bookshelf.js

I need to drop table for test suite, (using mocha on express framework). I can't find a way to simply do something like:

```
bookshelf.dropTable('tablename');
// or
SomeModel.dropTable();
```

How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use knex to drop the table you can use the instance you passed to bookshelf

```
Bookshelf.knex.schema.dropTable('table name').then(...);
```